# Quick Hypberbolic Geometry question concerning Saccheri Quadrilaterals

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Can a Saccheri Quadrilateral have 3 congruent sides? I know the summit is less then the base, but could it happen that the base is the same length as the two vertical sides?

Comment: To make sure we agree on definitions: *A Saccheri quadrilateral is one with two equal sides lying at right angles to the base.* There's no stipulation about the relative length of the base, so the answer to your question(s) is "Yes". (BTW, the summit edge is *longer* than the base edge in hyperbolic geometry. (Well, they're congruent if they both have zero length.))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a Saccheri Quadrilateral with three congruent and one larger side is possible. The following image is a screenshot of the hyperbolic plane, rendered in the Poincaré disc model, with a construction executed using [Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/).

[image: Screenshot from Cinderella]